# Error instantiating org.picocontainer.web.PicoServletContainerFilter

Tags: java, instantiationexception, picocontainer

I'm green in Java development. I'm trying to use `PicoContainer` in a servlet application. I configured the container in the `web.xml` and it fails when it try to create the filter.
So I tried to instantiate the filter manually like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.picocontainer.web.PicoServletContainerFilter");
Object test = clazz.newInstance();
```

and I obtain the same exception:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException
```

but I have no detailed message. I guess something is missing in the JAR in deployment ( shouldn't have in this case `ClassNotFoundExeption`? )

because it is not clear to me the dependency needed. ( Seems the old dll hell era )
At the moment I'm deploying the following jars:

- picocontainer-2.10.2.jar
- picocontainer-web-core-2.4.jar
- xstream-1.3.1.jar

What is the problem? Is it a missing Jar or something else? If there is a missing Jar and because I have no additional message, how can I understand what Jar is missing? Deployng the whole picocontainer jars is not the preferred option since it is a huge mess of files.

**EDIT**

Problem seems that the class is abstract!
So I don't know how this configuration found in the docs can works:
http://picocontainer.com/web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer myself.
Problem was of course `org.picocontainer.web.PicoServletContainerFilter` being abstract. There is an implementation in that class called servlet filter. Here the working cofig:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's just some wrong example code. You don't need filter at all for basic IoC composition. org.picocontainer.web.PicoServletContainerListener  does all the job configuring application/session/request containers.

Mind it requires a the class name of the WebappComposer type as a context-param in web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
   <param-name>webapp-composer-class</param-name>
   <param-value>com.company.MyWebappComposer</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

You need filter impl if you want to inject servlet context to you app scoped components, http session to the session scoped ones and http request to request scoped.

Comment: while you posting I found myself a solution. Sure it will work even on a per request base without a filter?

Comment: That's actually yes and no. It depends on your needs. Listener is enough to compose containers as I said, Filter just adds Context/Session/Request instances to the containers if you need them.
So if you want to have http request injected to you request scope components and http session injected to your session scope components, you will need the filter.

Comment: well is just because I probably will have a DAO injected who will open the connection at each request